# Automate git-pull, stuck with keychain

Tags: git, shell, unix, command-line-interface, keychain

I'd like to create a cronjob to automatically run a git-pull every minute.
The problem is that my repo is private, I had to create keys on my system (Ubuntu Server 12.04). I installed keychain and ssh-agent now prevents the system from asking me the passphrase everytime. The problem is that it doesn't work from crontab! Why from shell it works and from crontab I get asked the passphrase?

Comment: Also, just to be clear, git pull doesn't require a passphrase when running under your standard environment, correct?

Comment: Ok, update. I closed the connection, reconnected and now in "standard environment" keychain works and I don't have to insert the passphrase until `ssh-agent` is "alive". Problem is with crontab. I added a:
`*/1 *   * * *   root    cd /PATH_TO_REPO && git pull >> ~/git.log` but I get a `"Host key verification failed. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly."`
The same command (`git pull`) from "standard environment" works fine now though...

Answer (score 2):

In your script, are you doing an `$(eval ssh-agent)`, and then an `ssh-add <private_key>`?

To verify, do an `ssh-add -l` before doing the git pull to make sure your keys are where they should be.

[edit]
Try making a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e 
cd /var/www/GITREPO 
eval $(ssh-agent) 
ssh-add /home/multiformeingegno/.ssh/id_rsa
ssh-add -l
git pull
```

Comment: See my latest comment above. ;)

Comment: Yeah try it all in a script:

    #!/bin/bash
    set -e
    cd /PATH_TO_REPO
    eval $(ssh-agent)
    ssh-add <private_key>
    ssh-add -l ## to check
    git pull

Comment: I tried running `#!/bin/bash set -e cd /var/www/GITREPO eval $(ssh-agent) ssh-add /home/multiformeingegno/.ssh/id_rsa ssh-add -l` in shell but I receive no feedback

Comment: `ssh-add -l` gives me the fingerprint and location of the keys, so they're correct.

Comment: I tried the script but I receive a: `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git.` of course I set the REPO path for `cd`.

Comment: Ugh.. wanna try again?  re-edited the script

Comment: It works!! The only problem is the damned passphrase. The script still asks it, dunno why! :( With a simple "git pull" from the git repo dir I'm not asked for it.. weird.

Comment: The weird thing is that the same command from shell doesn't ask me the passphrase, called from a .sh file it does!

Comment: Anyway keychain should allow me to avoud adding the key everytime

Comment: Here is a usefull doc I found:

Don't forget that you can also get your cron jobs and scripts to "hook in" to the running ssh-agent process. To use ssh or scp commands from your shell scripts and cron jobs, just make sure that they source your ~/.ssh-agent file first:

source ~/.ssh-agent


Then, any following ssh or scp commands will be able to find the currently-running ssh-agent and establish secure passwordless connections just like you can from the shell.

Comment: DONE! With this it doesn't ask me the passphrase, because keychain is called:
`source ~/.keychain/$HOSTNAME-sh
cd PATH_TO_REPO
git pull`

Answer (score 0):

better then a cronjob, I propose the hooks/post-receive script :

First, in my .bashrc :

```
[ -x /usr/bin/keychain ] && /usr/bin/keychain ~/.ssh/id_rsa || echo "Missing keychain pkg..."
[ -f ~/.keychain/$(hostname)-sh ] && source ~/.keychain/$(hostname)-sh
```

Which asks for passphrase at first login (necessary) for the keychain ss-agent to register as you know.

Then, in the bare repository :
/path/to/bare/repo.git/hooks/post-receive :

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh <host> sh << EOF #I launch sh here for less verbosity on terminal login
. ~/.keychain/\$(hostname)-sh
cd /path/to/cloned/repo.git
unset GIT_DIR
git pull
EOF
```

don't forget to :

```
chmod +x /path/to/bare/repo.git/hooks/post-receive
```

this way, from my dev clone of the bare repository, the production one is automatically updated.